How to compute $\pi_1$ of $S^n$ with a diameter attached?
This is a past qualifying exam problem.

Let $X$ be the union of the standard $n$-sphere $S^n \subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$, $n \geq 1$, with the diameter $\{(x,0,\dots, 0) \mid -1 \leq x \leq 1\}$. Compute $\pi_1(X)$.

I can solve this for $n=1,2$, but I'm stuck on how to think about this in dimensions higher than that.
For $n=1$, by collapsing the diameter, we see that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1 \vee S^1$, so we get $\pi_1(X)=F_2$, the free group on $2$ generators.
For $n=2$, we can use Van-Kampen's theorem with $U,V$ being open $\epsilon$-neighborhoods of the upper and lower hemispheres of $S^2$, respectively, together with the diameter. Then $U\cap V$ is a thin strip around the equator of $S^2$ with the diameter attached. We get that $U$ and $V$ are homotopy equivalent to a $2$-disk with a handle, and thus homotopy equivalent to $S^1$. Hence $\pi_1(U)=\pi_1(V)\cong \mathbb Z$. Then $U\cap V$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1 \vee S^1$, so $\pi_1(U\cap V)\cong F_2$. Computing the pushout of the maps $\pi_1(U\cap V)\rightarrow \pi_1(U)$ and $\pi_1(U\cap V)\rightarrow \pi_1(V)$ induced by the inclusions, we get that $\pi_1(X)\cong \mathbb Z$. (A more complete argument appears in the answer to this question).
For $n \geq 3$, I don't really know where to start. I know that spheres can be defined inductively (via $S^{n+1}:=\Sigma S^n$ where $\Sigma$ denotes the suspension), so maybe there is an inductive argument somewhere here? Or, perhaps there is some way to show that $X$ is always homotopy equivalent to a wedge-sum, e.g., of $S^n$ and copies of $S^1$? But I'm not sure how to carry out that argument.

Hint: There's a space homotopy equivalent to $X$ whose fundamental group is easy to compute. Example 0.8 in Hatcher may be useful.

Think of it as the unuon of the sphere and a topological circle.

Isn't this just $S^n \vee S^1$, which we can see by moving the endpoints of the diameter to a single point?

@Smiley1000 That would be what Moishe Kohan and myself have been hinting at, yes. Also "moving the endpoints of the diameter to a single point" requires some justification, see e.g. my answer.

Let $X_n$ denote the (homotopy equivalence class of) an $n$-sphere with a diameter attached, say between $a=(1,0,\cdots,0)$ and $b=(-1,0,\cdots,0)$. We note $\pi_1(X_0)$ is trivial, $X_0$ being an interval ~ a point.
We can apply the Seifert van Kampen theorem inductively; your approach for $n=2$ generalises. There are simpler ways, but I just wanted to note your method was already good enough.
If $U,V$ are $X_n\setminus\{(0,0,\cdots,1)\},X_n\setminus\{(0,0,\cdots,-1)\}$ then these are open path-connected sets covering $X_n$, given $n\ge 1$, and $U\cap V$ is homotopy equivalent with $X_{n-1}$. Indeed $U,V$ deformation retract onto upper/lower hemispheres union the diameter, and these retractions are compatible and the intersection deformation retracts onto the subspace $X_n\cap\Bbb R^n\times\{0\}\cong X_{n-1}$.
A hemisphere union the diameter is just an $n$-disc with a handle; these deformation retract onto subcircles. You can see $\pi_1(U),\pi_1(V)\cong\Bbb Z$ where both may be taken to be generated by the loop which pass $a\to b$ along the diameter and then move $b\to a$ in a great circle within $S^{n-1}\subset X_{n-1}\subset X_n$. If $n=1$, there is only one choice of great circle which lies within $U$, $V$ respectively (for this purpose) but if $n\ge2$ we may choose any; that is, we may take $\pi_1U,\pi_1V$ as both being generated by the same loop in $X_n$.
If $n=1$, $X_{n-1}$ has trivial fundamental group so the group pushout is just $\Bbb Z\ast\Bbb Z$. If $n=2$, the two free generators $\alpha,\beta$ of $\pi_1(X_1)$ are identified in $U$ and in $V$ and $U,V$ may both be taken as generated by the same loop, indeed we can take it to be $\alpha$, so the amalgamated free product is just free on one generator (say, $\alpha$) with the two copies of $\alpha$ (one in $U$, one in $V$) being identified. If $n\ge3$ we may inductively assume $\pi_1(X_{n-1})$ is free on one generator, this same loop I described above (move along the diameter and come back along a great circle in $S^{n-1}\subset X_{n-1}\subset X_n$) and we have a very similar situation of $\Bbb Z\ast_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Z\cong\Bbb Z$ where the maps two $\Bbb Z\rightrightarrows\Bbb Z$ could be taken as the identity maps.
So: $$\pi_1(X_0)=\{1\},\,\pi_1(X_1)\cong F_2\\n\ge2:\,\pi_1(X_n)\cong\Bbb Z\text{ with generator either of the two canonical generators of $\pi_1(X_1)$}\\\text{If one views $X_1\subset X_n$ }$$

Since FShrike has provided a van Kampen solution, here's another, somewhat shorter argument:
Consider $S^n$ as a CW-complex with the "inductive" cell structure, i.e. such that $S^n$ is obtained from $S^{n - 1}$ by attaching two $n$-cells, all the way down to $S^0$. Assume now that $n > 0$, let $D \subset X$ be the diameter and assume without loss of generality that $D \cap S^n = S^0$, i.e. that the endpoints of $D$ are the 0-cells of $S^n$. Let $L \subset S^n$ be the union of $S^0$ together with one of the two 1-cells of $S^n$. Then $L$ is a contractible subcomplex of $X$, so the quotient map $X \to X / L$ is a homotopy equivalence, and $X / L \simeq S^n \vee S^1$ (make sure you understand why!). Thus, we find that
$$
  \pi_1(X) \cong \pi_1(S^n \vee S^1) \cong \pi_1(S^n) * \pi_1(S^1) \cong \begin{cases}
         \mathbb{Z} & n > 1 \\
         \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z} & n = 1
       \end{cases}
$$
just as in FShrike's answer.

You can literally copy and past the exact proof that you included in your post in your paragraph "For $n=2$...", with a few minor changes, for the separate case "For $n \ge 3$..." :
Of course, replace each $S^2$ with $S^n$.
And then make this replacement:

"$U \cap V$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1 \vee S^1$, so $\pi_1(U \cap V) \cong F_2$"

becomes

"$U \cap V$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^{n-1} \vee S^1$, so $\pi_1(U \cap V) \cong \mathbb Z$"

